# How to get first 1000 entries of each individual?

Tags: r

I have a huge dataset which includes several variables, giving example of two variables Animal ID and GPS location. Animal ID is unique to each animal. Each individual animal has atleast 4300 GPS locations. I need the first 1000 locations for each individual in a single dataset so that I could run the correction code as a test run.

I have been trying a lot of methods but I could get the first 1000 points but not per individual.

Comment: Could you please show what has failed? A sample of your dataset with `dput(head(df,n))` is also necessary for better reproducibility.

Comment: Base R option: `do.call(rbind, by(x, x$AnimalID, head, n=1000))`. In future questions, Srivats Chari, please show efforts you have attempted: not only does it inform the type of solution offered (e.g., base R, `dplyr`, `data.table`), it also demonstrates that this is not a "lazy question" (no effort made, assume others will do work for you).

Answer (score 2):

With `dplyr`:

```
your_data %>% 
  group_by(AnimalID) %>%
  slice(seq_len(1000))
```

With `data.table`:

```
your_data[, .SD[1:1000, ], by = .(AnimalID)]
```

With base R (from d.b's comment)

```
your_data[with(your_data, ave(AnimalID, AnimalID, FUN = seq_along) <= 1000),]
```